# Is the set of rational numbers a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the set of all rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ a vectorspace?

I assumed no, because if
$$\vec{x} \in \mathbb{Q}$$ 
$$\pi \vec{x} \notin \mathbb{Q}$$ failing scalar mult closure

This was a question out of my linear algebra book, looking at the solutions says that it is a vectorspace. Am I making an incorrect assumption?

Comment: A vector space over *what* field?

Comment: A vector space is a concept that relates, among other things, two sets. One of them is usually called the vector space while the other is what I call here *scalars set*. The answer depends on what you take for scalars set.

Comment: $\pi\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.  You can only scale by elements in the field the vector space is over, and I assume the field is $\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Any question that asks if this or that set is a vector space is a wrong question. To be a vector space, one needs to specify a set, a field, an addition operation and a scalar product operation. Then one needs to check the axioms. Without that, the question is meaningless.

The intention was probably to ask whether $\mathbb Q$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb Q$ with the ordinary notions of addition and multiplication, which it is. Your argument in the question shows that $\mathbb Q$ is not a vector space over $\mathbb R$ with the usual addition and multiplication. But, if the field is not specified, and the operations are not specified, then really the question is just meaningless. In particular, one can endow $\mathbb Q$ with infinitely many different vector space structures over infinitely many different fields. For that matter, the set $\mathbb N$ can also be endowed with infinitely many such vector space structures.

Answer (score 16):

Any field is a vector space over itself.  So, yes, the rational numbers are a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Is the set of rational numbers a finite dimensional vector space over $Q$ ? @ncmathsadist

Comment: Every field is a vector space over itself of dimension one.

Comment: How one finds bases of a vector space ℚ over the field ℚ? Do "finitists" in the philosophy of mathematics actually hint that axiom of choice is wrong (especially with the hints from quantum mechanics resolving the Gibbs paradox)?

Comment: Any nonzero rational is a basis for the rationals over themselves.